# Testing a component that calls an external function with Jest and React Native Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-native-testing-library

Suppose I have a component that calls a function, for example:

```
// AComponent.js

import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { getAString } from "./utils/function";

const AComponent = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{getAString()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AComponent;
```

and suppose `getAString` is in another file, and it's as simple as:

```
// function.js

export function getAString(): string {
  return "This comes from GetAString";
}
```

I want to test `AComponent` but with the function mocked:

```
var AComponent = require("../src/AComponent").default;
import { getAString } from "../src/utils/function";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react-native";

describe("A Component's test", () => {
  it("mocking the function", async () => {
    render(<AComponent />);

    jest.spyOn(AComponent, "getAString").mockImplementation(() => {
      return "This is a mocked result";
    });

    const element = screen.getByText("This is a mocked result");
    expect(element).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

It fails with this message:

```
Cannot spy on the getAString property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

I guess that it expects that function to be a property of `AComponent`. But how could I do it then?

Comment: `jest.spyOn` is looking for a property, and`getAString` **isn't** a property of `AComponent`.

Comment: But how could I do it then?

Comment: In your case I wouldn't bother - you want the component to render `"This comes from GetAString"`, so test that. That leaves you free to confidently refactor _how_ that string is produced. It's only if `getAString` gets substantially more complex (e.g. that string is on the other end of a network call) that you need a test double.

Comment: I'll do that, thank you